# Is it possible to train a model in keras with the gradient of the loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a model where I know the gradient of the loss function i.e dE/dy where E is the loss function and y is the output. However, it is not integrable and there is no closed-form of the loss function. Is there a way to train the model in Keras (using tensorflow perhaps) in this case?

Comment: What did you mean exactly by gradient of the loss function?

Comment: @abdou_dev gradient of the loss respect to the outputs, or simply an update rule for the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

Imagine you have all the variables of E, `x_i`, stored in `var_list` list. And imagine you have a list of pre-calculated gradients values for each corresponding variable, `dE/d(x_i)`, stored in `processed_grads`. With these assumptions, you can use `ops.apply_gradients` to apply these gradients to the values by this command:

```
opt.apply_gradients(zip(processed_grads, var_list))
```

If you look for a full example, here is the one I took from TensorFlow docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer):

```
# Create an optimizer.
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

# Compute the gradients for a list of variables.
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  loss = <call_loss_function>
vars = <list_of_variables>
grads = tape.gradient(loss, vars)

# Process the gradients, for example cap them, etc.
# capped_grads = [MyCapper(g) for g in grads]
processed_grads = [process_gradient(g) for g in grads]

# Ask the optimizer to apply the processed gradients.
opt.apply_gradients(zip(processed_grads, var_list))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, let's say I have an update rule for the outputs, for example, y=y-eta*y where y is the output. And I want to backpropagate this. How would I be able to implement that in the above framework?

Comment: Also, how do I get the var_list? In my case, the var_list would be the variables of the output of the model.

Comment: normally the optimizations works in this way: y = y -e*y' where y' is the gradient. the optimizer parameters ( like 'e' or learning rate) are set in the second line, where we declare `opt`. var_list are the set of model parameters. if you're function y=f(x)= Ax1+Bx2+C, the var_list is like [x1,x2] and the gradient_list is [g1,g2].

Comment: feel free to read more about the optimization process and how gradients are actually woking during the backprop. I shared the doc of tensor flow, looking at it can be helpful too. Good luck

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot